# WPF GUI Performance with a large number of parallel tasks

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, async-await, task

I developed a small client (WPF) to make some stress test on our systems. Essentially it has to call various methods on an Asp.Net WebApi endpoint in parallel.

Each time you press "Start" it generates 4000 tasks (Async - Await) in parallel with request to stress, waits until they all finish, then it does it again - until the user clicks the stop button. The GUI is decorated with a progress bar and some counters: requests in error, completed request, in progress requests. I obtain these informations because the object that makes the batch of stress requests exposes some events:

```
var stressTestTask = new stressTestTask(LogService, configuration);

stressTestTask.ErrorRequestCountChanged += stressTestTask_ErrorRequestCountChanged;
stressTestTask.GoodRequestCountChanged += stressTestTask_GoodRequestCountChanged;
stressTestTask.TryRequestCountChanged += stressTestTask_TryRequestCountChanged;

_executionCancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();

await Task.Run(
    () => stressTestTask.ApiStressTestTask(_executionCancellationToken.Token),
    _executionCancellationToken.Token);
```

The whole execution is started from an `ICommand` (MVVM):

```
private RelayCommand _startCommand;
public RelayCommand StartCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _startCommand ?? (_startCommand = new RelayCommand(
            async () =>
            {
                await StartStressTest();
            }));
    }
}
```

`RelayCommand` is an implementation of `ICommand` from the library `Mvvm-Light`.

What I don't understand is this behaviour: if I configure my batch of tasks with a "low" number of tasks, for example 2000, the GUI doesn't freeze while executing. If instead I choose 5000 tasks, after a while it freezes. If then I open another instance of the .exe of my client and I choose 2000 on each, the GUI is responsive in both.

My first question is: why opening one instance with `x` tasks is worse in terms of responsivness than opening `n` instances with `x/n` tasks? Is it something related to Windows Scheduler and the fact that in the first case I have only one process?

My second questions is: how can I address the problem to make everything work on a single GUI? I thought about making a console application with the single batch of stress tests and calling a command from the GUI for each instance I want, in order to generate a process for every batch.

Comment: Are you using `HttpClient` to call the endpoint?  If so bear in mind that `HttpClient` uses `HttpWebRequest`, which has a default limit of 2 concurrent connections per host.  Hence with larger numbers of connections you would expect better total throughput from multiple instances of your test client.

Comment: I'm calling the autogenerated client from WCF xsd definitions. But your comment is very interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you handling those API events by invoking to the UI context? If you have many invocations occurring you will flood the dispatcher with operations and cause the UI to hang and lag behind user input.

Try batching the UI updates.

Comment: How to batch UI Updates?

Comment: @AZ_ The answer to that question is not a comment. Please start a new question, alternatively, google is your friend https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiIiqmGh5rUAhUHKMAKHQPMAKIQFggoMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F10927298%2Freactive-extensions-process-events-in-batches-add-delay-between-every-batch&usg=AFQjCNEKfAiX56db5ajFLu2RwovOBtJqwg&sig2=TsrgB07DQmguBzEZQjkEaA

Comment: I have been googling my whole day bro! didn't find any solution for batching multiple updates.

Comment: @AZ_ if you find yourself spinning up a question on the topic i will put in answer for you.

Answer (score 2):

> My first question is: why opening one instance with x tasks is worse in terms of responsivness than opening n instances with x/n tasks?

Possibly because you are getting more events to handle on the UI thread. I guess your ErrorBetCountChanged, GoodRequestCountChanged and TryRequestCountChanged event handlers are invoked on the UI thread and a lot of events being raised may flood the UI thread.

As Gusdor suggets you should probably find a way of batching the updates. Take a look at the reactive extensions (Rx): http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/01_WhyRx.html.

It has a Buffer method that may come in handy: http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/13_TimeShiftedSequences.html.

It also has en Obervable.FromEvent method that you can use to convert an event into an IObservable: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229241(v=vs.103).aspx.

> My second questions is: how can I address the problem to make everything work on a single GUI?

You need to find a way - one or anoher - of updating the UI less frequently. Batching the updates and events should be a good starting point. Raising less notifications is another option. Maybe you need to both.

Answer (score 1):

> how can I address the problem to make everything work on a single GUI?

Send API requests in "proper" async-await manner with only one thread.

```
private async Task SendStressRequests()
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4000; i++)
    {
        var task = SendApiRequestAsync();
        tasks.Add(task);
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    // Update UI with results
}
```